# Extending service in the same docker-compose.yml file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Let's say I have a service like:

```
my-service:
  build:
    context: "./my-service"
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  ports:
    - 8072:8000
  depends_on:
    - another-service
  environment:
    PROXY: "true"
```

And I want to create `my-service-2` with exactly the same configurations but only with different port. I could do this:

```
my-service-2:
  build:
    context: "./my-service"
    dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
  ports:
    - 8073:8000
  depends_on:
    - another-service
  environment:
    PROXY: "true"
```

But is there any way I could do something like:

```
my-service-2 extends my-service:
  ports:
    - 8073:8000
```

So I wouldn't need to rewrite the same thing many times.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extends is supported till compose v2.1 although its usage is not how you asked for.

You need to keep the common configurations in one compose file and in the docker-compose.yml you can define the services extending from the common compose configuration.

Here is an elaborate example and documentation on this:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/